# Connect moment-range with sails backend

Tags: momentjs, sails.js, moment-range

I want to get date range between start_time and end_time.

```
 var newrange = sails.moment.range(start_time, end_time);
```

But it says,

```
 TypeError: sails.moment.range is not a function
```

Comment: Can you show the complete code which you import moment js?

Comment: const Moment = require("moment");
const MomentRange = require("moment-range");
const moment = MomentRange.extendMoment(Moment);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting up the imports like below and then run the function:

```
const moment = require("moment");
const momentRange = require("moment-range");
momentRange.extendMoment(moment); 

var newrange = moment.range(start_time, end_time);
```